# Join two paths to become one?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, path

I have two lines intersecting forming a cross. I outline the strokes but they continue to be individual lines in stead of one path. I want these lines to be one undivided line but cant get there?

Answer (score 2):

### From the Pathfinder panel use Unite to combine your shapes:

[(Illustrator Help / Combine objects using Pathfinder effects)](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/combining-objects.html#pathfinder)

*Left: before / Right: after*
[image: Pathfinder Unite]